# Relation about derivatives.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) \leq g(x) \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$, is there any relation between $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ and $g^{(n)}(x_0)$, the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ ($n=1,2,3\dots$)? What I got so far is that for $n=1$ $f'(x_0) = g'(x_0)$, but I couldn't get anything more for higher order derivatives. Also, consider the case particular case $x_0 = 0$.

Thanks in advance,

best regards.

Comment: How did you get $f'(0)=g'(0)$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh $f(x) = f(0) + f'(x)x + o(x)$ and $g(x) = g(0) + g'(x)x + o(x)$, substracting both we get $g(x) - f(x) = \underbrace{g(0)-f(0)}_{0} +(g'(x) - f'(x) + o(1))x$. Since $g(x) - f(x) \neq 0$ then taking $x \to 0$ we could have a problem if $g'(0) \neq f'(0)$.

Comment: Your argument does not seem correct.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh we have ${f(x)-g(x)\over x} = f'(0) -g'(0) + o(1)$ and the left quantity must always be of the sign of $x$.

Comment: @user251257 we don't have $g \geq f$. Consider $x = -1$.

Comment: Actually you have typo in question. You should write $0$ instead of $x_{0}$ and then your conclusion is OK.

Comment: Right. This is the particular case $x_0 = 0$. Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h = g - f \ge 0$. Than, $x_0$ is a minimizer of $h$ and thus $h'(x_0) = 0$. Further you obtain $h''(x_0) \ge 0$. You could apply every necessary conditions about minimum you want.

In particular, if $h''(x_0) = 0$, you obtain 
$$ h(x) = \frac16 h'''(x_0)(x-x_0)^3 + o(|x-x_0|^3) \ge 0$$
and 
$$ h'''(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{6 h(x)}{(x-x_0)^3} = 0, $$ 
as 
$$ \frac{h(x)}{(x-x_0)^3} \begin{cases}\ge 0, & x > x_0 \\ \le 0, & x < x_0.\end{cases} $$
And so on...

Notice, you can't say anything about $h'''(x_0)$ if $h''(x_0) > 0$.